# Dynamic table creation with nested json data

Tags: jquery, html

i have a nested json file. Using that data i want to create a dynamic html
table using jQuery using $.each loop.

Here every row is a category with the three languages.
Was able to accomplish using getJSON method for simple json data.

```
  [{
                "CategoryId": 1,
                "CategoryTexts": [{
                        "LanguageId": 1,
                        "Description": "Netus.",
                        "CreatedById": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "LanguageId": 2,
                        "Description": "Elementum.",
                        "CreatedById": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "LanguageId": 3,
                        "Description": "Rhoncus!",
                        "CreatedById": 3
                    }
                ],
                "CreatedById": 1,
                "IsActive": true
            },
            {
                "CategoryId": 2,
                "CategoryTexts": [{
                        "LanguageId": 1,
                        "Description": "Aptent!",
                        "CreatedById": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "LanguageId": 2,
                        "Description": "Et.",
                        "CreatedById": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "LanguageId": 3,
                        "Description": "Pellentesque.",
                        "CreatedById": 6
                    }
                ],
                "CreatedById": 2,
                "IsActive": true
            }            
        ]
```

Table headers would be:

```
<th>Language 1</th>
<th>Language 2</th>
<th>Language 3</th>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan "Write a solution for me" probably :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it iterating the data..

```js
var data = [{
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "CategoryTexts": [{
                "LanguageId": 1,
                "Description": "Netus.",
                "CreatedById": 1
            },
            {
                "LanguageId": 2,
                "Description": "Elementum.",
                "CreatedById": 2
            },
            {
                "LanguageId": 3,
                "Description": "Rhoncus!",
                "CreatedById": 3
            }
        ],
        "CreatedById": 1,
        "IsActive": true
    },
    {
        "CategoryId": 2,
        "CategoryTexts": [{
                "LanguageId": 1,
                "Description": "Aptent!",
                "CreatedById": 4
            },
            {
                "LanguageId": 2,
                "Description": "Et.",
                "CreatedById": 5
            },
            {
                "LanguageId": 3,
                "Description": "Pellentesque.",
                "CreatedById": 6
            }
        ],
        "CreatedById": 2,
        "IsActive": true
    },
    {
        "CategoryId": 3,
        "CategoryTexts": [{
                "LanguageId": 1,
                "Description": "Metus.",
                "CreatedById": 7
            },
            {
                "LanguageId": 2,
                "Description": "Quis?",
                "CreatedById": 8
            },
            {
                "LanguageId": 3,
                "Description": "Rhoncus.",
                "CreatedById": 9
            }
        ],
        "CreatedById": 3,
        "IsActive": true
    }            
];

var columns = ""
data.forEach(function(e){
  var column = '<tr><td>'+e.CategoryTexts[0].Description+'</td><td>'+e.CategoryTexts[1].Description+'</td><td>'+e.CategoryTexts[2].Description+'</td></tr>';
  columns+=column;
});

var table = $('<table><tr><th>Language 1</th><th>Language 2</th><th>Language 3</th></tr>'+
  columns+'</table>');
  $('body').append(table);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :

```
objJson = JSON.parse(json);
    $.each(objJson , function(i, obj) {
          $("#myTable tbody").append("<tr><td>" + obj.CategoryTexts[0] + "</td><td class='job'>" + obj.CategoryTexts[1] + "</td><td class='id'>" + obj.CategoryTexts[1] + "</td></tr>");
});
```

Adapt with anything you want from your Json object